# Binding datagrid in datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

Why i cant bind datagrid property selected item ?
i have property in my ViewModel

```
    protected TheFile curentFile ;
    public TheFile CurentFile
    {
        get { return curentFile; }
        set { curentFile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurentFile"); }
    }
```

And here is my datagrid:

```
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"   Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding SameFileGroups}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurentGroup}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Всього" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding TotalSizeInDirectory}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="1 файл" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding OneFileSize}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurentFile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Шлях" Binding="{Binding Path=Destination}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Розмір" Binding="{Binding Path=SizeBytes}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="md5" Binding="{Binding Path=Md5Hash}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

But this binding doesnt works

```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurentFile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: Your binding is referencing `Files`, your property is named `CurentFile` ...

Comment: im talking about SelectedItem property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have problem with `DataContext` here.

In `RowDetailsTemplate` you trying to binding to a property in main view model, but `DataContext` of `RowDetailsTemplate` is the row item.

If you want to binding to property in your main view model you should use `RelativeSource` binding.

Try this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Files}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.CurentFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    ...
```